# JavaScript match multiple values in comma separated strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have a string with a bunch of numbers

```
var matches = '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97';
```

and I would like to check with a different sub string if the values matches with the within the string provided above

```
var numbers = '126,125';
```

I have tried the regular expression

```
if( $(this).attr('data-ids').match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+matches+"(?:,|$)"))){console.log('found'); 
}else {console.log('not found')}
```

But the regex works for a single value not for multiple values

```
var numbers = '125';
```

I want this to work with single and multiple matches.

Comment: Do you have `matches` or `numbers` variable? You pass `matches` to the regex, while you should pass `numbers`.

Comment: why not [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Is order significant? If `matches` contained `125,126` should it match your `numbers` when it's `126,125`?

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order does not matter, you could take a set and check every wanted item.

```js
var matches = '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    numbers = '126,125',
    has = numbers.split(',').every(Set.prototype.has, new Set(matches.split(',')));

console.log(has);
```

Comment: This one did the job I was getting two variables but did not know which one will be bigger so I use split and count the length of the array to know which one will be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the order in `match`. I'm assuming `numbers` variable has the value returned by `$(this).attr('data-ids')`. You need check if `$(this).attr('data-ids')` exists inside `matches` and not the other way round. Change it to:

```
if (matches.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)" + $(this).attr('data-ids') + "(?:,|$)"))) {
  console.log('found');
} else {
  console.log('not found')
}
```

Also, if you just want to check if the substrings exists, you can use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead

Comment: Hi @adiga Number variable might contain something like 
`
var numbers = '128,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97';
`
Which it will not find

I am searching the ids and matching with data-ids and if there is match I want to show them

And the role could be reversed matches keyword could be small like 126 ,125 which is a match as well either way I have to check them

Comment: @apoorv I'm so confused. Why have you reversed the variables? From the question it looks like `matches` has all the ids. But, now you are mentioning that `numbers` is the one which contains all the ids and `matches` has only limited number of ids. How is  `$(this).attr('data-ids')` realated to all this

Comment: Let me explain there are certain div that has their attributes data-ids matching the keys in the database so they could be one or a multiple values and I am running a ajax request upon search that gets the ids related to that search now the search result could be one id or multiple ids 
so that role could be reserved Basically I need to check the both variable and if match is found need to show the the div otherwise remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not significant (`numbers` could be `125,126` o4 `126,125` and you want both to match your example), you'll want to split those strings into arrays and then check whether the entries in the `numbers` are all in `matches`:

```
const match = numbers.split(",").every(n => matchesArray.includes(n));
```

Live Example:

```js
function test(matches, numbers, expected) {
    const matchesArray = matches.split(",");
    const match = numbers.split(",").every(n => matchesArray.includes(n));
    console.log(`matches: ${matches}`);
    console.log(`numbers: ${numbers}`);
    console.log(`match:   ${match}`);
    console.log(!match === !expected ? "=> Good" : "=> ERROR");
}

test(
    '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    '126,125',
    true
);

test(
    '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    '125,126', // <== I changed the order here
    true
);

test(
    '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    '119,126',
    false
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If order is significant, the easiest thing would be to put commas around them and do a substring check:

```
const match = ("," + matches + ",").includes("," + numbers + ",");
```

Live Example:

```js
function test(matches, numbers, expected) {
    const match = ("," + matches + ",").includes("," + numbers + ",");
    console.log(`matches: ${matches}`);
    console.log(`numbers: ${numbers}`);
    console.log(`match:   ${match}`);
    console.log(!match === !expected ? "=> Good" : "=> ERROR");
}

test(
    '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    '126,125',
    true
);

test(
    '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    '125,126', // <== I changed the order here
    false      // <== Shouldn't work
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, you posted just before my edit, nice one. Quick note, you log yes every time :)

Comment: need to append the commas with `numbers` also

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
(','+matches+',').search(','+numbers+',')>=0;
```

```js
var matches = '128,126,125,124,123,122,118,117,116,115,99,98,97',
    numbers = '126,125';
    
let r= (','+matches+',').search(','+numbers+',')>=0;

console.log(r);
```